# Microsoft Access VBA pop up alert date approaching

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to write some VBA in Microsof Access (if VBA is the way to go?). What I need is a pop up message alerting someone that a deployment is happening within the next week.

My table is called Tasks_List and there is a field called Deployment_Date.

What I think I need is to put together an OnLoad for the initial form. It would check today's date and check through Deployoment_Date and show a pop up if any deployments are happening within the next week. The pop up should show what deployments are happening e.g. Initiating_System, Deployment_Date and Description.

Thank you in advance, I've hit a brick wall on this. I'll post what I've tried but I have no VBA knowledge and it is pretty bad.

What I tried:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim varX As Variant
varX = DLookup(Tasks_List.[Deployment_Date]< Now - 20)
If varX > 0 Then GoTo line2


line1: msgbox "Deployment approacing for: "

line2:


End Sub
```

EDIT: After help below I have created a query and form for this. Using Dcount:

```
Private Sub Detail_OnLoad()
    Deploy = DCount("*", "Tasks_List_Popup_Query")

    If Deploy <> 0 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Tasks_List_Popup_Query_Form"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need any VBA. Create a query that selects the relevant records and create a form based on the query. You can use DCount to ensure that there are records before you launch the form, which would take a little VBA.

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks_List WHERE [Deployment_Date]< (Date - 20)
```

For the DCount:

```
Deploy = DCount("*","TheQuery")
```

Comment: Hi, firstly thanks a million! I have a query put together now, and I have created the form from it. I tried the code part on the Intro form (the default on loadup): Added to question above! However, this does not seem to execute.

Comment: There are a few possibilities. Do you know how to set a breakpoint and step through code? You can set a breakpoint by choosing a suitable line, say `deploy=` ans pressing F9, now open the form that runs the code. The cursor should stop at the breakpoint, if it does not, that is problem one, get back to me. If it does, use the immediate window (ctrl+G) to check that Deploy holds a suitable value, first press F8 to run the line, next type `?Deploy` and hit return in the immediate window, if there is a problem there, get back to me.

Comment: Thanks again. I put the code onto a button and it is executing correctly! However, I can't seem to trigger the 'OnLoad' for the form Dashboard_Home. I'll keep hacking. Thanks for the tips on Debugging it has been a LOOOONG time since I've seen it. MUCH apprecciated!

Comment: Most welcome. Make sure the the On Load line contains `[Event Procedure]`

Comment: Form_Load() rather than Form_OnLoad() seems to be the trick, but your advice on [Event Procedure] is what got it all sorted out. :) Brilliant!